# Why can I access folder when login but not though SQL job

Tags: security, ssis, jobs, sql-agent-job, shared-directory

SSIS is easy, security is hard. :)

I'm having issues with an SSIS running as a SQL Agent job that cannot find the shared folder paths for input files.

I extracted a working SSIS project from Prod, redefined the connections to point to Dev, and deployed it to Dev. The jobs on Dev run under a different service account than Prod. The network team setup permissions to allow the Dev SQL Agent service account to access the folders.

If I log into the Dev server using the SQL Agent service account, I can see the shared network folders (named as "\\mainDir\subfolder\subfolder"), I can move files, etc. But when I run the job on Dev it dies in validation with error "Directory "\\mainDir\subfolder\subfolder" does not exist". It definitely exists.

What am I missing? And thanks!
If it matters, SQL Server 2016, Windows servers, SSIS project is in the Integration Services Catalog.

Comment: Is this network share on Windows? Maybe check that the access has been granted on both the security tab as well as the sharing tab, only granting to the security tab sometimes causes this problem